# Please share the process to merge C++ plugins from Autodesk 2016 to Autodesk 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins, revit-api, autodesk

We have several plugins working in C++ with Autodesk 2016 so now wants to have these plugins working on Autodesk 2022 by upgrading Autodesk version. Please share the complete procedure for this.

Please share complete details of Autodesk Revit tool.

Answer (score 0):

The steps for migrating Revit add-ins from one release to the next have been documented in full with many examples by The Building Coder in the category [migration](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/migration). As you probably know, the Revit API is .NET based, so the migration steps are independent of the programming language used. In many cases, no code modification is required from one release to the next, unless obsolete functionality is used. Obsoleted properties and methods are highlighted in the Revit API documentation included with the Revit SDK and also shared by The Building Coder in the articles on [What's New in the Revit API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/11/whats-new-in-the-revit-20221-api.html#2).